# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bridj/cpp/CPPObject

Tags: java

Here I have written some code to capture the image from My Pc cam using java.
**Below is the code:**

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
    int number = rnd.nextInt(999999999);

    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.open();
   String filename = "";
    filename = number + "_" + ".jpg";
    ImageIO.write(webcam.getImage(), "JPG", new File("src\\esprit\\com\\logo\\" + filename));
    pic = filename;
    System.out.println(filename);

    webcam.close();
```

And I have added  *slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar* ,  *slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar*,*webcam-capture-0.3.12.jar* And *webcam-capture-driver-v4l4j-0.3.11-sources.jar*  what ever required, but when running the application, image is not getting, Exception is raised.

**Below is the Exception:**

```
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:72)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:140)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$WebcamNewGrabberTask.newGrabber(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:45)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver.getDevices(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:117)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:36)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService$WebcamsDiscovery.call(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bridj/cpp/CPPObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDriver$WebcamNewGrabberTask.handle(WebcamDefaultDriver.java:55)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:81)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bridj.cpp.CPPObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

**N.B** My IDE is Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4

Comment: Google is your [friend](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/114#issuecomment-19814595).

Comment: if you've a solution add it in the answer section and never inside the question. PS: as you simply forgot to add some jar file you could also eventually delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a jar unspected, see https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/248

You only need add this bridj jar, you can download it http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbridj062jar.htm

Good lucky